# Sharp edges were baked with normal map

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I was baking my normal map while I had sharp edges baked with it too even tho it is smooth in the high poly version. It seemed like it almost baked the whole topology with it also..I also smooth out my low poly version..

Here is the sharp edges I'm talking about:
[image]

Here is the sharp edges that appeared on the normal map:

[image]

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your blend file?

Comment: Here you go

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=G8GOa3Nm" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/G8GOa3Nm/)

Comment: Bake (and reference) your normal map as non-color data.  This takes care of the problem you're demonstrating.